# SESSION returns old value when echoed in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

```
<script language="javascript">
            function emergency()
            {
                if(document.getElementById('emer').checked == true)
                {
                    <?php $_SESSION['total2']= $_SESSION['total1'] + 50; ?>
                    document.getElementById('emr').innerHTML = "<b>Payable Amount: </b>" + <?php echo  $_SESSION['total2']; ?>;
                }
                if(document.getElementById('emer').checked == false)
                {
                    <?php $_SESSION['total2']= $_SESSION['total2'] - 50; ?>
                    document.getElementById('emr').innerHTML = "<b>Payable Amount: </b>" + <?php echo  $_SESSION['total2']; ?>;
                }
            }
            </script>
```

here I am adding `$_SESSION['total1']+50` and put the value in new session `SESSION['total2']`. The problem is that , when I echo this new `$_SESSION['total2']` out side script,ie, in the page like

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['total2'];?>
```

it returns the value of $_SESSION['total1']).

Comment: For sessions to work you need to reload the page using for example <?php header('your-url-to-the-page'); ?>

Comment: Can you try `$_SESSION['total2'] = (int)$_SESSION['total1'] + 50;`?

Comment: you are doing +50 and -50 in total2  ... so no changes in total2

Comment: Well, you first add 50, then you subtract 50? Or are you referring to first echo?

Comment: @vonUbisch@user1844933@D. Kasipovic@Nishant Solanki@user3383167:even if I change the code as $val= 30 + 50; and initialise a session outside script and then echo, the result is 30,ie, the first operand in the addition process.

Comment: Maybe stupid but could happen; have you started the session using `session_start()`?

Comment: @vonUbisch: nice joke.....but not in a condition to laugh...sorry..

Comment: It wasn't my intention to joke, but to come to a solution for your problem. This has been easily forgotten many times here on SO.

Comment: @vonUbisch:sorry if it hurted you.But the problem is solved by using ajax call to set the session value....thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Are you calling a javascript function to change value of php session variable?**..
this could not be possible because, **php is a server side language and javascript is client side** so php code gets executed when the page is loaded..

so if you want to do this on javascript function call,, than you need to use `ajax`...

Comment: :now i just changed the code like $tot=$_SESSION['TOTAL1']+50 and outside javascript I initialized a session normally as $_SESSION['total2']=$tot .Then I echoed it. Still the same result.

Comment: the thing is that **you can not change php variable value using javascript**.. but by using `ajax` you can..
please refer this answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540000/how-to-insert-javascript-value-into-the-php-session-variable

Answer (score 1):

to get the new value of `$_SESSION['total2']` you have to run the code on server side again. that means before getting the new value for total2 session variable you have to reload the appropriate php file.

Comment: :innerhtml displays correct values.but  when i echo value anywhere else ,it returns session['total1'] value even after reloading the page.