# How to initialize ajax request into php variable (for a another php function)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I want to send a JavaScript variable `Data` into another php file for a php function.  [I realized we are unable to use PHP Sessions for that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540000/how-to-insert-javascript-value-into-the-php-session-variable) I tried to do it using AJAX (using jQuery), but I am unable to initialize the AJAX request in to a php variable. However AJAX give me a correct Response:(means ajax is working). but when i print the request [print_r($_POST)], it gave me zero result.

Here is the main html , javascript part.

```
<div id ='postData'>"+ PostDataResponse + "</div>  // PostDataResponse is also ajax response, it is working correctly.
<a href='server.php' onclick= saveData()> click_Here_Link </a>
```

When I click the click_Here_Link link I wont send the data to requestFile.php file as session variable. I developed the ajax post method in client side like this.(It give me a correct response.)

```
  function  saveData(){

     // $.post('/ server.php', { postingData: name});

     var name = document.getElementById("postData").innerHTML.trim();

   $.ajax ({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'server.php',
   dataType: 'text',
   data: {postingData: name},

  success: function (Response) {
     alert(Response);
  },
   error: function () {
   alert('failure...!  ');
   } 
 });
 }
```

Here is the server.php code.

```
<?Php
  $boat = $_POST['postingData'];
  echo $boat;
  print_r($_POST); 
?>
```

when open the server.php file it give me a error.

> Undefined index: postingData

Comment: What does just `print_r($POST);` give you? Where exactly is the error?

Comment: are you opening server.php in your browser? you need to look under your browsers dev tools and view the network tools tab then fire your ajax and view the response to the post if(isset($_POST['postingData'])){ /* do something post not set*/ } will check if $_POST['postingData'] is set

Comment: It gave me  "Undefined index: postingData"  and   "Array ( )"  as error #FrankerZ

Comment: @DushmanNalin, check if my answer works for you

Comment: @futureweb, ajax code is working correctly. it gave me a correct response. I wont  initialize ajax request into php variable,(in server.php )  like session variable.

Answer (score 1):

replace your ajax with this :

```
 $.ajax ({
   method:'POST',
   url: 'server.php',
   data:"postingData="+$('#postData').getAttribute('name'),
  success: function (Response) {
     alert(Response);
  },
   error: function () {
   alert('failure...!  ');
   } 
 });
```

Comment: It gave me same error..

Comment: have you tried changing the method to get? some times it works! @DushmanNalin

Comment: Yes, I also tried using get.. #abdollah zakeri.

Comment: if print_r($_POST) returns an empty array then nothing is being set..

Comment: you could try using .done instead of success  $.ajax({ */ your params */ }).done(function(data){ alert(data); }).fail(function(){ alert('it failed')});

Answer (score 1):

Edit the following in ajax
.change name to name2

```
data: {postingData: name2},
```

Comment: it was a typing mistake, I have changed real variable name in to this question.